# the residue of the function $e^{-e^{1/z}}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

the residue of the function $e^{-e^{-1/z}}$

since we can write $\displaystyle e^{- \{1+\frac{1}{z}+\frac{1}{2!Z^2}+\frac{1}{3!z^3}+......\}}$
this means that 0 is the pole
how we going to processed for further step

Comment: $0$ is **not** a pole.

Comment: The title and the text differ in a sign.

Answer (score 1):

$$e^{-e^{1/z}}=1-e^{1/z}+\frac{1}{2!}e^{2/z}-\cdots$$
$$=1-\left(1+\frac{1}{z}+\frac{1}{2!z^2}+\cdots\right)+\frac{1}{2!}\left(1+\frac{2}{z}+\cdots\right)-\cdots$$
$$=1-\frac{1}{z}\left(1-\frac{1}{1!}+\frac{1}{2!}-\cdots\right)+O\left(\frac{1}{z^2}\right)$$
$$=1-\frac{e^{-1}}{z}+O\left(\frac{1}{z^2}\right)$$

Comment: You have missed the constant terms $\left(1-\frac{1}{1!}+\frac{1}{2!}-\cdots\right)=\frac1e$. The answer should be $\frac1e-\frac{e^{-1}}{z}+O\left(\frac{1}{z^2}\right)$